# Why doesn't my character sheet work with input() when trying to choose a race in a text based adventure? python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, decision-tree, fsm, design-decisions

So this is just the beginning of a long line of questions I know that I am going to have. In this text based adventure I would like to eventually have puzzles and multiple branching paths, factions you can eventually join, choice dialogue that affects the morality of situations(like mass effect or kotor but.. text based-ish), etc., etc., but I feel like the early set up is VERY important for this learning journey. I also would like to eventually convert it over to PYQT5 and maybe eventually host it with a UI on a website I've built for my portfolio. I just wanted to get that out of the way in case you see me on here a lot. PM me with advice for that if you'd like(Because I definitely could use the help from a patron saint!).

## Okay, so the problem at hand is:

I have a list of races to choose from:

```
races = ['Human', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Dragonborn', 'Tiefling', 'Half-Elf']
```

I would like for it to ask the player to 'Choose a race'.
After the player types what they want to play it asks 'Are you sure?'
|Here is where I am stuck|
If the player says 'yes' it ends the program and I can attempt to continue building this application.
If the player types 'no', it doesn't return back to the original question and allow them to answer it again.

So, the things I have tried are defined as different methods:

```
Character.charRace()
Character.charDict()
Character.charTry()
```

I think my poor code attempts speak for themselves in terms of what I've been trying.

```
class Character:

    def charRace():
        raceOptions = ['Human', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Dragonborn', 'Tiefling', 'Half-Elf']
        raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')

        if raceChoice == 'Human':
            res = input(
                """
                Choose Human? 
                (Y   /    N)
                """)

            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            if res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')
                res = input(
                    """
                    Choose Human? 
                    (Y   /    N)
                    """)

        if raceChoice == 'Dwarf':
            res = input(
                """
                Choose Dwarf? 
                (Y    /    N)
                """)
            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            if res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')

        if raceChoice == 'Elf':
            res = input(
                """
                Choose Elf? 
                (Y   /    N)
                """)

            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            if res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')

        if raceChoice == 'Dragonborn':
            res = input(
            """
            Choose Dragonborn?
            (Y    /    N)
            """)

            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            if res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')

        if raceChoice == 'Tiefling':
            res = input(
            """
            Choose Tiefling?
            (Y    /    N)
            """)

            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            if res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')

        if raceChoice == 'Half-Elf':
            res = input(
            """
            Choose Half-Elf?
            (Y    /    N)
            """)

            if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
            while res == 'N':
                del raceChoice
                raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')
                res = input(
                    """
                    Choose Half-Elf?
                    (Y    /    N)
                    """)

        if raceChoice == 'Orc':
            res = input(
                """
                Choose Orc?
                (Y    /    N)
                """)
            while res:
                if res == 'y':
                    print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
                    break
                if res == 'n':
                    del raceChoice
                    raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \n')
                    res = input(
                        """
                        Choose Orc?
                        (Y    /    N)
                        """)

    def charDict():
        raceOptions = ['Human', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Dragonborn', 'Tiefling', 'Half-Elf']
        raceChoice = input(f'Choose a Race: {raceOptions} \nRace: ')
        if raceChoice == 'Human' or 'human' or 'h':
            print(f'Choose {raceChoice}?\n')
            ans = input()
            if ans != 'Yes' or  'yes' or 'y':
                print(f'You chose {raceChoice}! ')
            elif ans == 'No' or 'no' or 'n':
                return raceChoice
            if raceChoice != 'Human' or 'human' or 'h' or 'Dwarf' or 'dwarf' or 'd' or 'Elf' or 'elf' or 'e' or 'Dragonborn' or 'dragonborn' or 'DB' or 'Tiefling' or 'tiefling' or 't':
                return 'That is not a race that can be chosen at this time!'

    def charTry():
        races = ['Human', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Dragonborn', 'Tiefling', 'Half-Elf']
        res = input(f'Choose a Race: {races}. \nRace: ')
        race = res.capitalize()
        if race in races:
            if race == 'human' or 'Human' or 'h':
                print(f'Do you want to choose {race}? ')

    Character.charRace()
    Character.charDict()
    Character.charTry()
```

### Desired Result Example:

```
>>> f'Choose a race {races}!:
>>> Human
>>> Do you want to play a Human?
>>> (Y    /    N)
>>> N
>>> Continue to browse...
>>> Choose a race: Human, Dwarf, Elf, Dragonborn, Tiefling, Half-Elf
>>> Dwarf
>>> Do want to play a Dwarf?
>>> Y
>>> You have chosen to play a Dwarf!
```

I've tried a few different methods to acquire the desired result but they don't seem to work.
Should I build a finite state machine? How would I do that? What is the best method for longevity and making the code modular for future update?

Comment: A way you can make your code a lot more maintainable, is to maybe create a function called `confirmation` that does the confirmation on what race you play. I see a lot of repetition in your code with that. It seems like you are familiar with how f strings work, so I think you could condense that code to that. 

I also notice that when you hit "N" you aren't recalling the function. Try doing something like `self.charRace()`

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If i was to use `self.charRace()` would I need to set up a `__init__()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are try to do is to build a menu, where the user may make choices and confirm and retry their choices as often as necessary.

The way to do this is with an infinite while loop.  Essentially, you just want to keep repeating the same set of options until the user makes a selection, or quits.

Also, try to keep your code indifferent to the particular selection that the user makes.  We care that they select an item from the list; we don't need to care *which* item, as long as we have some way of retrieving it when necessary.  In the following code, note that there is no explicit mention of the individual races except in the original list.

```
class Character:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    RACES = ['Human', 'Dwarf', 'Elf', 'Dragonborn', 'Tiefling', 'Half-Elf']                                                                                      

    def choose(self):
        # list choices as (0) Human, (1) Dwarf etc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        choices = ', '.join([f'({i}) {race}' for i, race in enumerate(self.RACES)])    
        # Loop forever!                                                                          
        while True:                                                                                                                                              
            choice = input(f'Choose a race: {choices} ')                                                                                                         
            choice = choice.upper()                                                                                                                              
            if choice == 'Q':                                                                                                                                    
                print('Bye!')  
                # Break out of the loop                                                                                                                                  
                break                                                                                                                                            
            elif not(choice.isdigit()):                                                                                                                          
                # Not a number                                                                                                                                   
                print('Sorry, please choose a number')                                                                                                                       
            elif not 0 <= int(choice) <= len(self.RACES):                                                                                                        
                # Number outside the range of choices                                                                                                            
                print('Sorry, please choose again')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            else:   
                # The number input by the user matches the position
                # of their choice in the list of races                                                                                                                                             
                selection = self.RACES[int(choice)]                                                                                                              
                confirm = input(f'You chose {selection} - confirm (Y/N)? ')                                                                                      
                if confirm.upper() == 'Y':                                                                                                                       
                    print(f'Confirmed - you\'re a {selection}!')
                    # Break out of the loop                                                                                                 
                    break                                                                                                                                        
                else:                                                                                                                                            
                    print('OK, let\'s try again')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        return
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do! I couldn't get the while loop to work without it just creating infinite versions of the 'Choose a Race: ' option.

Comment: Just a few follow up questions to make sure i get it: You put RACES in all caps because its a constant variable? And to simplify readability you enumerated?

Comment: Re RACES - yes, though of course it needn't be a constant.  Using `enumerate` is more readable (and less cumbersome) than looping over the list and incrementing a counter variable.  Note your original approach - the user types in the full name of their choice - would work fine, but you want to minimise the amount of typing required, both for user convenience and because you'll be going through a _lot_ of menus while testing your program.

Comment: Gotcha! Last question I swear! Just for the sake of applying what I've learned: If I was to add a descriptor, something like - "You've chosen {selection} - Would you like to see a description?" Would I use a dictionary `RACEDESC = {'Human' : "+1 Str, Bipedal, Speaks 'Common'", 'Dwarf' : "" etc}` or would the descriptions be in a list just like RACES and the index would be tied to the index position of the RACE? I tried it with a `while` loop with the dict but it told me that there were too many values to unpack so i wasn't sure why? You have helped a lot sorry for the trouble!!

Answer (score -1):

There is a really easy way to do it. You need to import 'time' module by `import time`
or you can use the easiest way, add `while True:` at the beginning of the code. !!Don't forget the spaces after ":"!! Then after each if statement you need to add 'continue' like this: `if res == 'Y':
                print(f'You Chose {raceChoice}!')
                continue`