# Obtaining user input in a Python program

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

Let's say I want to create a input that is something like this

`Do you want a Porsche / y . n: n`

`Do you want a Ferrari / y . n: y`

`Do you want a Lamborghini / y . n: n`

and so on with 7 different cars of this to pick your choice.

And then the answer would be: `Ok, you can have choice 2`

How can I attempt this?

Comment: are you asking how to get inputs or how to use them?

Comment: I am not sure. I can tell you I only know about the car=input question, if car1 == "y":, if car2 == "y": and so on and and elif car1 == "n":, elif car2 == "n" and so on.

Comment: Similar problem, though not about cars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812428/why-doesnt-my-character-sheet-work-with-input-when-trying-to-choose-a-race-in/58825527#58825527

Comment: A very similar problem was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59005811/2745495. Instead of cars, it’s about ice cream. But the input format is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
ferrari =input("do you want a ferrari? y/n")
if ferrari=="y":
    print("here is your ferrari")
if ferrari=="n":
    lambor=input("lanborgini then?")
    if lambor == "y":
        print("here is your lamborgini")
    if lambor == "n":
        print("keep with the another cars")
```

Or you can try this

```
    def Cars(what):
    what = input("do you wanna a " + what)
    if what=="y":
        print("ookey!")
    if what=="n":
        print("we have more cars")
Cars("ferrari")
Cars("peudgeot")
Cars("mcqueen")
Cars("corsa")
Cars("nissan")
```

#you can add more cars#

Answer (score 1):

```
list = ["Lambo", "Ferrari", "Kia"]
responses = []
for car in list:
  choice = input("Do you want {} y or n?".format(car))
  responses.append(choice)

for i in range(0, len(responses)):
  if responses[i] == 'y':
    print("Ok, you can have choice {}".format(i+1))
```

You can create a list of all your 7 cars and record user responses for each car. After collection all responses, you can check if the user responded yes for a particular response and display it.

Below is the output when I run it:

```
Do you want Lambo y or n?n
Do you want Ferrari y or n?y
Do you want Kia y or n?n
Ok, you can have choice 2
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to use list and get the index of selected car. Since Python starts at index zero, we need to add one(Python 3.6+ using f-format):

```py
cars_models = ['Porsche', 'Ferrari', 'Lamborghini']

for car in cars_models:
    is_wanted = input(f'Do you want a {car} / y . n: ')

    if is_wanted == 'y':
        car_wanted = car

selected_choice = cars_models.index(car_wanted)

print(f'Ok, you can have choice {selected_choice +1}')
```

We first create a list of cars we want to check. Then we loop with questions. If the answer is `y`, we record which car. At the end we find the location of wanted car.

Before you celebrate, we have some issues we could take care. These are what-ifs: what if the user **selects** all n. Our current script will crash as `car_wanted` will be referenced before assignment. Solutions: Ask forgiveness > permission

```py
# ...
try:
    select_choice = cars_models.index(car_wanted)
    print(f'Ok, you can have choice {select_choice +1}')
except UnboundLocalError:
    print('Hmm, you have no choice')
```

Okay, this will catch that error. We are not done. What if the use answer (N/No/no instead of n, Y/Yes/yes instead of y)? What should we do when they input something completely out of scope. E.g. 'quit'?

As a programmer you need to try see these issues and address them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without duplicating code:

```
cars = ['car1', 'car2', 'car3', 'etc']

ans = []
for i in range(len(cars)):
    ans.append(input(f'Do you want {cars[i]}? (y/n) '))

for i in range(len(cars)):
    if ans[i].lower() == 'y':
        print(f'Ok,  your chose is {i+1}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add more to the list "cars" to ask the user their response to other cars.

```
userChoice = ''
cars = ['Porsche', 'Ferrari', 'Lamborghini']
c = 0

while(userChoice != 'y' and c < len(cars)):
    chooseCar = cars[c]
    userChoice = input(f"Do you want a {chooseCar} / y . n: ")
    c += 1

if(c == len(cars)):
  print("You don't want any of the cars.")
else:
  print(f"Ok, you can have choice {c}")
```

Also this I'm checking if the counter "c" is less than the length of the list because it will crash of there are no more cars to reference.