# How to obtain user input in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to learn how to code this.

Here is how I want it to look

```
Do you want strawberry ice cream? (y:n) n
Do you want chocolate ice cream?  (y:n) y
Do you want mint ice cream? (y:n) n
Do you want vanilla ice cream? (y:n) y
```

then the output would be: `Here is your ice cream.` or if you put N to all, `You did not say yes to any.`
Or with the else statement: `I didn't get that, try again.`

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

My test script:

```py
def kind(chosenIce):
      chosenIce=input("Do you want a ice cream (y:n) ")
      if chosenIce1 == 'y':
          ice1 = print("message")
      if chosenIce2 == 'y':
          ice2 = print("message")
      if chosenIce1 == 'n':
          ice1 = 0
      if chosenIce2 == 'n':
          ice2 = 0
      else:
         print("Sorry, I did not get that. Try again.")
kind(chosenIce)
```

Comment: A few examples: Why are you overriding the argument `chosenIce` in the first line of the function? Where do `chosenIce1` and `chosenIce2` come from? What is supposed to happen from `ice1 = print("message")`?

Comment: A very similar problem was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59005266/2745495. Instead of ice cream, it’s about cars. But the input format is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some fellows said, you have to use `input` and `loop` (i.e `for loop` or `while loop`) to achieve your goal. By reading your post and the comments, it seems you are really a newbie in Python. So, below, I give you a basic workflow that does something like your needs. There are many ways to achieve your goals. You can look at my workflow for inspiration.

Here is the code:

```
def kind(ices_cream):
    choices = []
    for ice in ices_cream:
        chosenIce = input('Do you want "{}" ice cream (y:n) '.format(ice))
        if chosenIce == 'y':
            choices.append(ice)
        elif chosenIce == 'n':
            print("You refuse ", ice)
        else:
            print("Sorry, I did not get that. Try again.")

    if len(choices):
        print("\n", "You buy", ' and '.join(choices))
    else:
        print("\n", "You buy nothing!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ices_cream = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Mint", "Vanilla"]
    kind(ices_cream)
```

> **Outputs:** It is an example

```
Do you want "Chocolate" ice cream (y:n) y
Do you want "Strawberry" ice cream (y:n) n
You refuse  Strawberry
Do you want "Mint" ice cream (y:n) y
Do you want "Vanilla" ice cream (y:n) n
You refuse  Vanilla

 You buy Chocolate and Mint
```

**NB:** You can add a loop `while` to force the user to input the characters `y` or `n`. Also, you can add exception handling if you want to do a good job.

Comment: This is a very helpful basic code, thank you for taking the time. I am super new to Python. I'd like to know is ```{}``` for ```choices=[]``` that links to ```ices_cream = ["Chocolate", "etc"]``` at the bottom?

Comment: `ices_cream = ["Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Mint", "Vanilla"]` is like the *menu* of the restaurant. So, in the logic, you pass the *menu* to a function that manage the customer order.

Comment: In the function `def kind(ices_cream): ...`, the list `choices` contains the client order. So, you will use this list later to print later something like `You buy Chocolate and Mint`. Keep in mind: there are many ways to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **only** what you want in this problem, you will use the function `input`. The way to use it is this:

```
strawberryIceCream=input('Do you want strawberry ice cream? (y/n)')
```

and so on, so forth with the other options as well. Remember to store each option in either a different variable or, better IMHO, in a set or tuple.

[Further info on `input`](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_input.php)

However, the comments' on your question are accurate and on point. This is why I mentioned that this answer will answer only your question. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I know how to do input, along with if, elif and else, I just do not know how to do the questions with the extra Y and N's. In my original code, I had if chosenIce1 == 'Y', if chosenIce2 == 'Y', and then the same thing with N, with the ice1 = 0 under it.

Comment: This is a very different matter, which you do not address in your question. You only wanted to know how to get user input, and I told you how to.

If you want an answer to this problem, please make another question.

Comment: @BeR see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
listQue=["Do you want strawberry ice cream?","Do you want chocolate ice cream?","Do 
you want mint ice cream?","Do you want vanilla ice cream?"]

flag=False
for que in listQue:
    ans=input(que)
    if(ans=='Y'):
        res=que.split()
        print("Here is your"," ".join(res[3:6]).rstrip('?'))
        flag=True
   else:
        pass


if(flag==False):
    print("Ohhh sorry you didn't choose anything")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 you can use `input()` (examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp)) and in python 2 `raw_input()` (examples [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/getting-user-input-from-the-keyboard)). You need to code the rest yourself using for-loops... etc.

Example:

```py
choices = []

x1 = input('Do you want strawberry ice cream? (y/n)')

choices.append(x1)  # store the choice for each question here so you can use it later for
                # selection criteria process. Store x2 at choices[1], etc.

for choice in choices:
    if choice in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', YES']:
        print ('User does like an iscream')
    else:
        print ('User no fan of the cold treat')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very simple and is super easy to understand now.

Comment: Your welcome. As you're also new to SO.. you can upvote more than one answer if more  answer did help you out to get what you want. I saw some of the answer are beyond beginners level therefor I kept it small and easy so you can play with it and learn easily.

Comment: @quamrana as OP stated to be a beginner I've chosen for a simple entry answer. No use to come-up with defs and classes in this case.

Comment: I’m sorry BeR, I’m not going to write code for you, now that you have removed yours from the question.

Comment: @quamrana if you found a typo... just fix it. ATM at a simple PC without language editor to run it. And I see what you ment with "removed code". Fixed.